# Urllib2 and proxies

Tags: python, urllib2

My problem is that a site blocks IP after every 1500 requests no matter if i extend sleep time. So i am using proxies while doing request. Bellow is the code which build an opener.

```
def getOpener(self, pip=None):
        if pip:
            proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': pip})
            opnr = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        else:
            opnr = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))
        opnr.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1')]
        urllib2.install_opener(opnr)
        return opnr
```

But when using proxies (high anonymous) the site hardly allow 40 - 50 requests. Why is that so? I think each proxy should do 1500 requests. So is there any thing i am missing? May be i need to pass some additional headers?

**(This is not a second question it is related with the first one)**

Also i found two different syntax of dict for ProxyHandler.

```
Syntax1:
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '61.233.25.166:80'})

Syntax2:
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://61.233.25.166:80'}) #see http:// in value
```

Does they have different meanings or they are same? What is best practice Syntax1 or Syntax2?

Comment: Normally if a site blocks a large number of requests from one person, they have very specific reasons. Depending on your goals, you may be able to contact the site maintainer directly to be granted an exception. Read their terms of service to see if crawling is discussed.

Comment: read the docstring for [`_parse_proxy()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/urllib2.py)